# Why trying to print unicode encoded strings with cout leads to compilation error in newer C++ standards?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, c++20, unicode-string

I tried the following printing of Unicode characters with Visual C++ 2022 Version 17.4.4 with C++ standard set to the latest.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << u8"The official vowels in Danish are: a, e, i, o, u, \u00E6, \u00F8, \u00E5 and y.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I have the compilation error:

```
1>C:\projects\cpp\test\test.cpp(7,8): error C2280: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char8_t *)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>C:\projects\cpp\test\test.cpp(7,8): error C2088: '<<': illegal for class
```

The same behavior is observed with `u` (utf-16) and `U` (utf-32) string literals.

Setting the standard to C++17 or C++14 makes the program to compile.

What is the rationale for disallowing this code in C++20 and later standards and what is the correct way to print Unicode string literals in those standards?

Comment: `std::wcout` works with strings of wide characters `wchar_t` (literals prefixed with `L`), but not for `char8_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t` strings.

Comment: `cout` is `basic_ostream<char>`. Can't imagine it could work with `char8_t`.

Comment: @273K Ok. This is a valid reason, but it does not explain why the code compiles under the older standards and how to print such strings in C++20 and later.

Comment: comment in cout implementation #ifdef __cpp_char8_t // These deleted overloads are specified in P1423.

Comment: https://rawcdn.githack.com/tahonermann/std-proposals/987667432726b9d9b748084e0c0f0cc114e3b408/p1423r3.html

Comment: It doesn't compile in C++20, because `char8_t` was introduced in C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until C++20, `u8"..."` was `const char[N]`. Since C++20, it is now `const char8_t[N]`.

`std::cout` is a `std::basic_ostream<char>`, and thus can't output `char8_t` data since C++20.

The possible [work around](https://godbolt.org/z/3oqYj1djs):

```
std::basic_ostream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char>& cout, const char8_t* s) {
  cout << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(s);
  return cout;
}

// Output: The official vowels in Danish are: a, e, i, o, u, æ, ø, å and y.
```

Comment: Ok. I will accept your answer if you also provide a solution on how to print such a literal in C++20.

Comment: I think your workaround leads to undefined behavior, because it attempts to [extend the namespace `std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) without any of the types being a program-defined type.

Comment: @heapunderrun It does extend the namespace `std`.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the rationale for disallowing this code in C++20

Firstly, in pre-C++20, there was no `char8_t` type. The `u8` prefix would simply produce `char` data while affecting its encoding.

C++20 introduced `char8_t` in [p0482](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r6.html), and backward incompatibly changed the `u8` prefix to produce `char8_t` data.

But, as [p1423](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r2.html) points out, that introduced a silent, counterproductive behavioral change, and the proposed solution was to make the operation ill-formed instead:

> An unintended and silent behavioral change was introduced with the adoption of P0482R6. In C++17, the following code wrote the code units of the literals to stdout. In C++20, this code now writes the character literal as a number, and the address of the string literal, to stdout.
>
> ```
> std::cout << u8'x';    // In C++20, writes the number 120.
> std::cout << u8"text"; // In C++20, writes a memory address.
> ```
>
> This is a surprising change that provides no benefit to programmers. Adding deleted ostream inserters would avoid this surprising behavioral change while reserving the possibility to specify behavior for these operations in the future (for example, to specify implicit transcoding to the execution encoding).

---

> what is the correct way to print Unicode string literals in those standards?

As of C++20, there has not been any standard way defined to print `char8_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t` as text directly. You will have to convert the Unicode data into the native encoding used by `char` or `wchar_t`, and then print that. There's no standard way to do such a conversion (that isn't deprecated), though.

The Unicode character types are generally useful for writing into files, but not so much for writing to standard output.